# how to add specific discord node js users in UserSelectMenuBuilder

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to add only two users to the selection, let's say they have IDs ('12321' and '2222') how do I show only them in UserSelectMenuBuilder

my code

```
 let select = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new UserSelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('select')
                .setPlaceholder(`Select users`)
        );
```

In the picture, I showed that I want to see only two users in the select, and not all who are on the server

[image]

I use Discord.js: v 14.14.1 and Node v20.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to do. As written in the documentation [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#select-menu-types), you can only define select options for string select menus. All other menu types are auto-populated. There is no way to filter the users in the user select menus.